# Running JUnit test suite using Maven

Tags: maven, junit

I have written a JUnit test suite for running multiple test cases.

Now I want to run my test suite class (AllTest.java) at once so that all tests are triggered, carried and managed by one class. I know maven-failsafe-plugin is available, but is there any other easier way to invoke a JUnit test suite from Maven?

I dont want to use another plugin for this.

This is my current maven-failsafe-plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/AllTests.java</include>
    </includes>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>integration-test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>verify</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>verify</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You could use default `surefire` plugin with the same configuration.

Comment: I dont want to use maven-failsafe-plugin, And i have tried with surefire plugin. But it is not picking up class which annotated as @RunWith(Suite.class) and @SuiteClasses({ TestClassMyPOJOBase.class })

Comment: Are you having unit tests or integration tests? Unit Test => maven-surefire-plugin, integration tests => maven-failsafe-plugin. You shouldn't work with suites, cause Maven-surefire or maven-failsafe will take care of running all tests. Furthermore don't forget the naming conventions for Unit tests and for integration tests.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run it with `-Dit.test=[package].AllTest` (`-Dtest` with surefire), or configure the included tests in the pom:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>AllTest.java</include>
      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: second option worked for me.. but -Dtest and Dit.test=[package].AllTest didnt really work for me.. Am I missing something??

Comment: I don't think fully qualified package names were supported until v2.19.1.  The snippet above references v2.12.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can run test suite using following maven command:

```
 mvn test -Dtest=x.y.z.MyTestSuite
```

Note : x.y.z is the package name.